# I tried to unpack 3 different list using ZIP. But i got an out with value mix up and quotes

Tags: python, list, indexing

I want to understand why the **output** is mixed up  and also has quotes,
I thought the zip function will sort the index

```
names = ['peter paker', 'clark kent', 'wade wilson', 'bruce wayne']
heros = ['spider man', 'super man', 'dead pool', 'bat man']
universes = ['marvel', 'DC', 'marvel', 'DC']

for names, hero, universes in zip(names, heros, universes):
    print(f'{names} is actually {heros} from {universes}')
```

**output**

```
peter paker is actually ['spider man', 'super man', 'dead pool', 'bat man'] from marvel
clark kent is actually ['spider man', 'super man', 'dead pool', 'bat man'] from DC
wade wilson is actually ['spider man', 'super man', 'dead pool', 'bat man'] from marvel
bruce wayne is actually ['spider man', 'super man', 'dead pool', 'bat man'] from DC
```

**expected output**

```
peter paker is actually spider man from marvel
clark kent is actually bat man from DC
```

Comment: You have to consider how / when  f-strings are constructed. Use different variable names for the zip() output and adjust your f-string accordingly

Comment: I'm also sure that your supposed *expected output* is not what you were expecting. See the answer from @Daweo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its just a typo. You meant to print the singular from the zipped plurals:

```py
names = ['peter paker', 'clark kent', 'wade wilson', 'bruce wayne']
heros = ['spider man', 'super man', 'dead pool', 'bat man']
universes = ['marvel', 'DC', 'marvel', 'DC']

for name, hero, universe in zip(names, heros, universes):
    print(f'{name} is actually {hero} from {universe}')
```

Answer (score 1):

Do not use name in for which is already in use in `for`..., do

```
names = ['peter paker', 'clark kent', 'wade wilson', 'bruce wayne']
heros = ['spider man', 'super man', 'dead pool', 'bat man']
universes = ['marvel', 'DC', 'marvel', 'DC']

for name, hero, universe in zip(names, heros, universes):
    print(f'{name} is actually {hero} from {universe}')
```

output

```
peter paker is actually spider man from marvel
clark kent is actually super man from DC
wade wilson is actually dead pool from marvel
bruce wayne is actually bat man from DC
```